# ffmpeg: Proper way to encode ac3 to aac?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have actually encoded an audio file from ac3 to aac using ffmpeg native aac encoder but the issue is that the file is not playing correctly , more specifically i have played that file in different media player but most of them start from 19 seconds and in vlc it is not even starting till I seek to more than 19 seconds duration.

command i have used is :-
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -map 0:a:0 -c:a aac audio.mp4.

Comment: Not really a programming question, but you might try using some of the other aac encoders: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC

Comment: You mean to say there can be issue with native aac encoder?

Comment: Without seeing the complete console output from your command there is little we can suggest.

Answer (score 8):

That is the proper way.

Don't know if this will make a difference, try `-b:a 400k` and `-strict experimental`.

If you want audio only, convert to `m4a` or `aac`.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -y -c:a aac -b:a 400k -map 0:a:0? -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Other encoders, may require compiling ffmpeg with use flags:

http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC

libfdk_aac

libfaac

Comment: `-strict experimental` is only needed with old `ffmpeg` versions and won't do anything helpful in this case.